# How to allow data attr in tags in Redactor HTML Purifer

Tags: redactor

I am looking to allow `data` attr in tags with Redactor content.

What should I add to the Default config settings to allow this attr?

Answer (score 1):

See this config setting: http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.AllowedAttributes

You should be able to use it to allow data attributes.

Comment: Thanks Clark, I am aware of the settings, however when I try something like this `"HTML.AllowedAttributes": ["img.src", "img.alt", "a.href", "*.title", "*.data"]` I get an error saying `Global attribute '*' is not supported in any elements`. Even if i try to set the attr to an element, it still doesn't allow it `Attribute 'data' in element 'a' not supported`.
I have also tried adding the `HTML.AllowedElements` setting too, to make sure the tag was allowed, but that made no difference.

Comment: Have you tried just `.data` or `data`

Comment: can confirm that using either ".data" or "data" will not work.

Comment: Was anyone able to get this to work?

Comment: @CreateSean - https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/38833/10878

Answer (score 1):

Found this, which may help someone who is smarter than I am go down a path to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29317456/584599